# Limiting SQL results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query that gives me the following results:

```
UserID | Msg

1      | Hello 
1      | What's up? 
3      | Blabla..
```

Is there something like an advanced LIMIT?

If simply LIMIT this result saying LIMIT 0,2 I'll get only the Msg's from user 1, but I want to get the Msgs from the first two users in the result (while not knowing what their ids are!)

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your query and table information?

Comment: How are you defining "first two users" - is the the two smallest UserIDs or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns what you asked for:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM t LIMIT 2) AS u 
INNER JOIN t USING (UserID);
```

Answer (score 2):

No advanced `LIMIT` are available.
For your situation you can use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
WHERE UserID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM `table_name` ORDER BY UserID ASC LIMIT 2
)
```

Comment: LIMIT is not allowed in subqueries in MySQL; could IN be replaced with EXISTS - I heard that is faster?

Comment: Hm, didnt hear about `LIMIT` limitations) Try to use `EXISTS`.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: Hm, failed to fo this) I think you should accept @Bill Karwin answer, it really works with only 2 records of `UserID`